# Call different subprocesses in different languages, ideally shared memory

Tags: parallel-processing, fork, bigdata, ipc, shared-memory

I am working on a big data solution. Usually I start with one chunk of big data, process it, send the results to the next tool to process it even more, and so on. Following is a small example how such a toolchain could look like. Mostly it is not deep (2 or 3 levels) and the fanout at the root is also usually smaller than 3. But fanout in the leaves can be easily 100.

These tools come from a variety of sources and can be closed source. So I have no way of bringing the in- and output of all tools to a common format. Also, the tools will be written in different languages. C, Java, Python, Bash, ...

The final product will be run on a server with quite a lot of RAM. So I would like to go to an in-memory, shared-memory solution.

The root tool is a mediator (Note: This would be my idea to solve my problems, I can be wrong of course and there would be a better approach). The mediator gets as input the toolchain (the selection and order of subprocesses will be chosen by the user), calls the different subprocesses, distributes data, recieves signals from the subprocesses when they are finished and the next one can be run. Subprocesses on the same level should be run in parallel.

So now to my questions: First of all - is this a good design? And second: Which API/functions/programming technique is best suited for calling all these processes so they share the RAM? (So maybe sharing RAM is not always possible. This is not so crucial.)

```
mediator
|-- toolA
|    |-- toolA1
|    |    |-- toolA11
|    |    +-- toolA12
|    +-- toolA2
|         +-- toolA21
+-- toolB
    |-- toolB1
    |-- toolB2
    +-- toolB3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I understand all of your question / explanations, but if you want to avoid using the file system to write intermediary files (the output ones from one tool that are input ones for the next tool) and if you have **enough memory available on your sever** to store these files, then you can consider using an in-memory file system.

If you are running on Linux for example, you can either use `/dev/shm` as base directory for your work, or mount a more convenient directory as `tmpfs`...

Comment: Thanks, this already helped a lot, but can you also answer how my calls to the tools should look like? tempf may be the solution for in-memory processing, but shared memory is even more important for my use case. And how would this work? popen(), fork(), ...?

Comment: I'd go for a shell script and the usual | < > suspects. Since you dont have access to sources, juste treat tour tools as black boxes and only make them interact through the in-memory file system.

Comment: Afaik the shell solution does not allow for shared memory. Not all tools are blackboxes and quite a few of them are our own work. Even when I use tempfs I have an overhead copying files to the memory segment for the next tool. I want to avoid this, too.
In the future there should also be a priority queue and maybe even more features we cannot yet think of. I don't think that a shell script will suffice. What options would there be in C to get the same results?

Comment: OK I'm not sure I've got all the bits here, but a possibility I see would be to use `/dev/shm` as file system for the tools that are black-boxes, (you can read/write in there like a usual file system), and to use the data there as shared memory segments for the tools you have the sources. Then `shm_open` and `mmap` are your friends...